# Two JPA/Spring Data entities with identical structure but different tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, spring-data-jpa

My application needs to store a set of "staging data" that has an identical database structure to another "real" table, but can't be written to the real table until a human reviews the contents of the staging data. These aren't just additions to the real table, but updates to it too (so, in other words, there are values in staging table with the same primary key as the real table as they refer to the same entity instance).

My approach is to have two JPA `@Entity` objects that have an identical structure (i.e. fields, column names, etc.) but are stored in different tables and treated completely separately from a Spring `CrudRepository` perspective (i.e. at no time do union queries occur to combine query results across both tables). However, I'd like to use inheritance to enable them to be treated interchangeably so that my application doesn't really know/care whether it's processing the real of staging data, and so I don't have to write a whole lot of boilerplate getter/setter/converter code.

So, what I have right now are essentially three classes:

1. `BaseEntity` that is annotated with `@MappedSuperclass` and identifies the common id property via the `@Id` annotation
2. An `Identifier` entity that extends `BaseEntity` and adds some other getters/setters for some other properties and has a `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` annotation
3. A `StagingIdentifier` entity that extends `Identifier` but has a different `@Table` annotation value (and adds no other fields or methods)

Given certain conditions, I want to essentially take the contents of the table holding `StagingIdentifier` objects and merge it (i.e. update existing entries, add new ones, etc.) into the table holding the Identifier objects. I'm using Envers for database auditing so don't really want to do any low-level database stuff that will mean I lose any auditability.

When I use a `CrudRepository<Identifier, Integer>` to try and save a list of Identifier objects when there are also StagingIdentifier objects saved to the database (with the same ID value), I get the following exception when Hibernate is trying to do the merge:

> org.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException: Object
>   [id=null] was not of the specified subclass [com.domain.Identifier] :
>   class of the given object did not match class of persistent copy;
>
> nested exception is org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object
>   [id=null] was not of the specified subclass [com.domain.Identifier] :
>   class of the given object did not match class of persistent copy

When I look at the SQL being generated by Hibernate, I see:

> DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select identifier0_.id as id1_10_0_,
>   identifier0_.level as level2_10_0_, identifier0_.name as name3_10_0_,
>   identifier0_.parent_id as parent_i4_10_0_, identifier0_.clazz_ as
>   clazz_0_ from ( select id, level, name, parent_id, 0 as clazz_ from
>   identifiers union all select id, level, name, parent_id, 1 as clazz_
>   from staging_identifiers ) identifier0_ where identifier0_.id=?

...so the above query is fetching both `Identifier` and `StagingIdentifier` objects - which explains the error.

So, is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: sorry didn't notice the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was restructuring my classes as follows:

1. `BaseEntity` = unchanged from my question
2. `AbstractIdentifier` = new abstract class that extends `BaseEntity` with a `@MappedSuperclass` annotation that all the properties, getters, setters, etc. of the `Identifier` class were moved into
3. `Identifier` and `StagingIdentifier` are now pretty much stub classes that extend `AbstractIdentifier` but have different `@Table` annotation values and their own Spring Data repositories

I then have written some methods to translate between `Identifier` and `StagingIdentifier` when needed (as much as I didn't want to have to) and unit tests to make sure of the correctness of these methods